# How to replace the strings '&amp;' for '&amp;&amp;' in a text field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

This is for SQL Server 2000 and I can't change that :(

I'm having some problems searching for the string

```
&amp;
```

and replacing it with

```
&amp;&amp;
```

I'm targeting a text field (not full-text indexed)

I have tried with

```
UPDATE documents
SET doc_xml = REPLACE(doc_xml, '&amp;' , '&amp;&amp;')
```

but this is not working as I have to escape the & char. I'd tried with

```
ESCAPE '\'
```

at the end, but no luck.

An example target content is this:

```
<FOLDER_Name>Buy&amp;&amp;Go</FOLDER_Name>
<PRODUCT_Name>Buy &amp;&amp; Go</PRODUCT_Name>
<SKU_Name>Buy &amp; Go</SKU_Name>
<COMPANY_Name>AT&amp;T</COMPANY_Name>
```

I want to replace only the single

```
 &amp;
```

in those last two lines, and the result I need to obtain is this one:

```
<FOLDER_Name>Buy&amp;&amp;Go</FOLDER_Name>
<Product_Name>Buy &amp;&amp; Go</Product_Name>
<SKU_Name>Buy &amp;&amp; Go</SKU_Name>
<COMPANY_Name>AT&amp;&amp;T</COMPANY_Name>
```

I have to keep spaces as in the original content and also don't modify the strings that already have a double ampersand

```
&amp;&amp;
```

Comment: what is the datatype of `doc_xml` column ? and you want to replace '&amp;' only in that four tag ?

Comment: @Krishnraj Rana Data type is text and I want to replace in all the tags.  Note: I already accepted  Xabi answer. Thanks for asking, I should have included that info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to do your replace twice, with the second one to fix the quad values.

```
declare @table table (x xml)
insert into @table
values( 
'<FOLDER_Name>Buy&amp;&amp;Go</FOLDER_Name>
<PRODUCT_Name>Buy &amp;&amp; Go</PRODUCT_Name>
<SKU_Name>Buy &amp; Go</SKU_Name>
<COMPANY_Name>AT&amp;T</COMPANY_Name>')

update @table
set x = convert(xml,
                replace(
                    replace(convert(varchar(max),x),'&amp;','&amp;&amp;'),'&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;','&amp;&amp;'
                    )

                )

select * from @table
```

If this isn't an `xml` column then:

```
declare @table table (x varchar(max))
insert into @table
values( 
'<FOLDER_Name>Buy&amp;&amp;Go</FOLDER_Name>
<PRODUCT_Name>Buy &amp;&amp; Go</PRODUCT_Name>
<SKU_Name>Buy &amp; Go</SKU_Name>
<COMPANY_Name>AT&amp;T</COMPANY_Name>')

update @table
set x =     replace(
                replace(x,'&amp;','&amp;&amp;'),'&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;','&amp;&amp;'
                )

select * from @table
```

So your code would be something like:

```
UPDATE documents
SET doc_xml = 
    convert(xml,
                replace(
                    replace(convert(varchar(max),x),'&amp;','&amp;&amp;'),'&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;','&amp;&amp;'
                    )

                )
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as it gave me the tip for adding CONVERT to the query, that at the end was the main problem I was facing, thanks.

Comment: Glad I was able to help @jaumenuez

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could work on SQL2000:

```
UPDATE documents
SET doc_xml =
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(CAST(doc_xml as varchar(8000))
            ,'&amp;&amp;', '&&'
                )
            ,'&amp;', '&amp;&amp;'
            )
            ,'&&', '&amp;&amp;'
        )
```

You can try on your SSMS:

```
DECLARE @doc_xml varchar(4000)
SET @doc_xml =
'<FOLDER_Name>Buy&amp;&amp;Go</FOLDER_Name>
<PRODUCT_Name>Buy &amp;&amp; Go</PRODUCT_Name>
<SKU_Name>Buy &amp; Go</SKU_Name>
<COMPANY_Name>AT&amp;T</COMPANY_Name>'

PRINT
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(@doc_xml
            ,'&amp;&amp;', '&&'
                )
            ,'&amp;', '&amp;&amp;'
            )
            ,'&&', '&amp;&amp;'
        )
```

Comment: EDIT: ohh that was on SSMS, but I get a message 'Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.' when trying to execute it on the table. The field's data type is TEXT. and I can't get a workarround.

Comment: Already fixed adding  convert (varchar(4000) .. in proper places: `UPDATE document
SET doc_xml = 
    convert(varchar(4000),
  replace(
   replace(convert(varchar(7000),doc_xml),'&amp;','&amp;&amp;'),'&amp;&amp;&amp;&amp;','&amp;&amp;'
  )
 )`

Comment: Solved with a single `CAST(doc_xml as varchar(8000))` at the 1st occurrence of `doc_xml`